# How to do Incremental statistics on auto_created stats(_WA_) in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, statistics

How to do Incremental statistics on auto_created stats(WA) in SQL server? I know I can do this for the non auto_created stats (indexed column) either by rebuilding index on the table or at DB level.

Is there any way to achieve this on auto_created stats(WA) also?

The underlying issue is-

On a good day query runs in 10 sec and on a bad day it take 5 min. This query uses 15 columns in a join on a large table. This table is partitioned. The only difference I found that on the bad run stats were also updated on those 15 columns at the same time query is running. please advise.

```
SQL Server 2017: 
is_auto_create_stats_on= True; 
is_auto_create_stats_incremental_on= False; 
is_auto_update_stats_on= True; 
is_auto_update_stats_async_on= False;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the default settings.

```
is_auto_update_stats_on= True; 
is_auto_update_stats_async_on= False;
```

So when you run a query that needs updated stats, the stats will update *before* your query runs.  You could update stats more agressively, or allow the query to run with the old stats while the stats are updated by turning on 'is_auto_update_stats_async_on'.

And yes, modifying an auto-created statistic to be incremental appears to work fine.  eg in AdventureWorksDW after partitioning FactInternetSales:

```
ALTER DATABASE current SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON (INCREMENTAL = ON)
GO
UPDATE STATISTICS [dbo].[FactInternetSales]([_WA_Sys_00000004_4E88ABD4]) WITH INCREMENTAL = ON
GO
UPDATE STATISTICS [dbo].[FactInternetSales]([_WA_Sys_00000004_4E88ABD4]) WITH RESAMPLE ON PARTITIONS(2)
GO
```